# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Opening project opens solution in parent folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, project

We have a master solution that has all 500 projects in it in a directory that the build uses.  The folder of solutions/projects is sampled below.

Solution1.sln
 \ProjectA\Project1.vbproj
 \ProjectB\Project2.vbproj

Starting with VS 2013 (Update 2), if a developer opens Project1.vbproj, Visual Studio now seems to open the Solution1.sln (and all 500 projects) which is not required and very slow for our developers.  VS 2013 (RTM) and VS 2013 (Update 1) did no behave this way.  Is this a bug or is there a way to disable this in VS 2013 Update 2.

Thanks

Scott

Comment: Hmm, I thought this behaviour existed since way back. A simple workaround is to move your solution file two folders up (and just change the project paths it references inside it with a search-and-replace in a text editor). You might also be able to fool it by putting a second solution file in the parent directory (surely it doesn't read *all* the solution files it finds on project load?) -- but note that I haven't tested either method.

Comment: Adding a dummy solution at the same level worked - thanks

Comment: Cool :D VS hack of the day.