# Does Visual Studio ever still try to open a solution in a parent directory when you open a project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio used to have a particularly strange, unhelpful behavior.    I am wondering if this still exists.  It doesn't seem to but I'm not sure if I'm testing wrongly.

The behavior consisted of VS trying to "help" you when opened up a single C++ project file by looking up the directory tree for a solution that contained it and then opening that solution if one was found.

This was incredibly annoying.  Sometimes you just want to open one project.  You don't want the entire, 37-project solution.  It got me into the habit of always putting solution files into their own, dedicated, subfolder, specifically to avoid this "feature".  Like this:

```
\ Solution Root Folder
    \ Solutions              (just to keep solution from being found)
        - MySolution.Sln
    \ Project1
        - Project1.vcxproj
    \ Project2
        - Project2.vcxproj
```

I just now tried testing to see if this behavior still exists and it would appear it does not.  But I want to see if anyone knows anything more definitive.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it does. Long answer: Yes, it does, and not only for C++ projects, but for all project types (judging from my experimentation). I don't think I can post this as an *answer* because I don't know how to stop it. But it's been [happening for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24959997/10871073). And it's still happening in VS-2022.

Comment: But maybe you need to clarify your question by *explicitly* asking if anyone knows a way to prevent this behaviour. (Rather than your vague, *"Does anyone know anything about this?*)

Comment: Well my workaround of putting solutions in their own subfolder does the trick to avoid the issue. Sorry if my question sounded vague.  For some reason my test could not reproduce the behavior.  I was wondering if maybe someone had specifically noticed this behavior no longer happening or even knew something specific about it (I've seen MS people on here before).  Anyway I'll stick to keeping my solutions in their own subfolders, thanks.

Comment: Incidentally I first noticed this behavior back in 2002, so it's a lot older than that thread you linked! :-)

Comment: I have a solution with a number of (very) different projects in it, which I use for testing code posted on Stack Overflow. I tried opening a number of the contained projects (C++, C#, CLR and Python) ... and each one opened up the parent solution.

Comment: Clearly I did something wrong in my test.  Thanks!

Comment: I even tried clearing the (hidden) ".vs" folder in the parent directory ... no joy.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem in vs2022. I have a vbproj in a folder, and VS always opens the solution in the parent folder which contains 47 projects. As yet I can't find a way to open just the project itself which is hugely frustrating. Edit: I was able to workaround the issue by copying the solution from upstairs, rename it to thisproject.sln, then use notepad to remove every project except this one.

Comment: This is apparently not a "bug" but a "feature".  In other words, they do it deliberately.   I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for them to change it.  The subfolder trick I mentioned previously works well.